# Jfree chart value Axis label is getting cropped

Tags: java, jfreechart

I am plotting the bar and line chart using the jfree chart .
One of the value axis is having the large label which doesn't fit in.
The label is suppose to be Greenhouse gas emissions (Tonnes).
Unable to find a  way to control the width of the lable or wrap it.

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart(chartDetails.getTitle(),
     chartDetails.getCategoryAxisLabel(), chartDetails.getValueAxisLabelLabelOne(),
     dataSets.get(0), 
     PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, 
     true, 
     false 
 );
 
 
final ValueAxis rangeAxis = new NumberAxis(chartDetails.getValueAxisLabelLabelTwo());
plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);
final Font yaxisFont = getFont(yaxisFontAttibutes, xfactor);
rangeAxis.setLabelFont(yaxisFont);
rangeAxis.setLabelPaint(Color.decode(yaxisFontAttibutes.getColor()));
rangeAxis.setTickLabelFont(yaxisFont);
rangeAxis.setTickLabelPaint(Color.decode(yaxisFontAttibutes.getColor()));
rangeAxis.setLabelFont(yaxisFont);
rangeAxis.setAxisLineVisible(false);
rangeAxis.setLabelInsets(new RectangleInsets(2, 2, 2, 2));

return chart.createBufferedImage((int) (chartAttributes.getWidth() * xfactor),
     (int) chartAttributes.getHeight() * xfactor);
```

Tried using LabelInsets but no use.
Note: I dont want to increase the heigth
Any sample code will be of great help.
Thanks

[image]

I have set the label at high end and rotated it .
But results are not desirable.

```
 rangeAxis.setLabelLocation(AxisLabelLocation.HIGH_END);
    rangeAxis.setLabelAngle(135);
```

[image: After rotating]

Comment: Hint: If you want a simple solution then you can reduce the font size based on the character length. For better help please show the code for the entire chart including how you create/use the `rangeAxis` object, and what the `xfactor` is.

Comment: I am scaling the image for higher resolution .hence the x factor.
I cant change the fonts or height .

Comment: If you go with a shorter label, use a `TextTitle` to elaborate.

Comment: @sorifiend even it is complex solution i don't mind implementing .
If you have any idea please share it

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code to see how this all fits together, there are too many unknowns, and it's a little confusing how you call your ValueAxis a rangeAxis. What is this line doing `plot.setRangeAxis(1, axis2);`, where do you actually add/set the rangeAxis of the chart? Anyway, that aside at a guess you could set a margin to the rangeAxis to force the label within the margin so that it doesn't get cut off, for example `rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(0.15);`. You can adjust the margin amount to suit your chart.

Comment: I believe this issue goes back many years, there any many things that alter the size of the chart and the plot/label locations, and they are not all aware of each other, so when you render the chart it heavily depends on if everything else has been done correctly (for example adding a correct offset to the label to counteract the other adjustments you have made). I hardly use this library, so I cannot really offer a complex solution other than encouraging you to play more with the padding and insets, or for more control you could manually add labels to the image after it has been generated.

Comment: @sorifiend  thanks for the inputs will try your suggestions.

Comment: @trashgod how did i rotate the textTitle any  reference would be helpful.

Comment: I'd stay with horizontal display for explanatory text.

Comment: @trashgod  But my requirement is vertical display.

Comment: As you are scaling the image for higher resolution, why not scale a chart large enough to display the entire label?

Comment: @trashgod I have already tried all those option my design team is not agreeing with those changes .Since the graph is getting squashed .I need to fit the chart in given space .